# Kali linux is getting slower because of using python3 and multithreading

Tags: kali-linux, qt, python3

I have Kali Linux operating system, and lately i have been working with python scripts ( creating GUI using python and QT5) and i am using multiprocessing and multi-threading in my code. 
However I noticed that lately that whenever I run the script, the whole laptop suffers from latency in responding, even when the script is over,  the laptop still doesn't restore its usual speed.

What i have done:

1. The device is up-to-date.

Simplified Version of the code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

#loading the GUI..
from GUI  import GUICLASS



class WorkerThread(QThread):
    request_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    Start_test= QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)
        print("init")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def doWork(self):
        self.request_signal.emit()


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def startTheTest(self):
        self.Start_test.emit("start the test")

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()
        print("this thread is terminating")


class theMainCode(QMainWindow, Ui_IoTTestbed, reportClass, FuncsToAddDevices):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initialize_GUI()



    def initialize_GUI(self):
        ####################### Start: Buttons ##############################
        #initialize Buttons
        self.button1.setEnabled(False)
        self.Button2.clicked.connect(self.startAPscript)


    def startAPscript(self, TestingDevice):
        self.startTheThread()




    def startTheThread(self, MAC):

        thread2 = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread2.start()
        self.worker2 = WorkerThread()
        self.worker2.moveToThread(thread2)
        self.worker2.Start_test.connect(lambda:self.startTesting(0,MAC))
        self.worker2.startTheTest()





    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def startTesting(self,number =0 , MAC="", second=False):
        if not second:
            self.tests=list(TestList.keys())
            print("loading tests: ", self.tests)

        if MAC in self.process and len(self.tests)==0 :
            print("if statment")
            return self.testsDone(MAC)
        print("\n\nThe tests left is:\n ", self.tests)
        time.sleep(2)

        for _ in range(len(self.tests)):
            script_name = self.tests.pop(0)

            self.runTest(script_name)

        if len(self.tests) ==0: #done empty..
            print("Test is done")
            self.testsDone(MAC)



    def testsDone(self, MAC):

        print("kill the threads")
        self.worker2.stop()
        #self.worker.stop()






    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QMainWindow, self).closeEvent(*args, **kwargs)

        if (self.worker != None):
            print("Killed = 1")
            self.worker.stop()

        if (self.worker2 != None):
            print("Killed = 2")
            self.worker2.stop()
        print("we are done")

        app.exec_()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = theMainCode()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How to check what is delaying the GUI response?

**edit

This is what i found as a result for `ps aux | grep kworker` : Please check the image attached. 
Some kworkers re-worked again the moment I opened the laptop again.
Moreover, I was not able to take a proper screenshot because the laptop is not responding very well.

[image: CMD results]

Comment: self.worker2.stop() is what should stop the qthread ??

Comment: try changing self.terminate() with self.quit() self.wait() in def stop of class WorkerThread(QThread):

Answer (score 0):

You could try `powertop` and `iotop` to check what is consuming most power and what is using the most disk IO respectively. Together with `top` those should be a decent indicator of what is actually happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Profile your python Code.
A profile is a set of statistics that describes how often and for how long various parts of the program executed. These statistics can be formatted into reports via the pstats module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Make sure to clean up threads, resources and close all handles.

Comment: following your advice i tried .. python3 -m cprofile script.py .. however it did not show anything when the script was done.

Comment: did you instanciate the cProfile object and called enable(), disable() and the print_stats() methods within your python code ?